# Unwanted space between list item

Tags: html

I have divs within each list item and the list items seem to have a space before each list item on IE and FF. I'm not quite sure why it's doing that because it's looking fine on Chrome. I searched online and tried putting margin and padding to 0 and also tried to put the code in the same line but I couldn't seem to get rid of the space above my div. The divs that I have here has jquery attached to it so I'm not sure if it affecting it in a way too? I checked online, some say only li should reside within ul/ol so I'm not sure if that's another reason to the unwanted space?

Just wondering if anyone knows if there a way to get rid of the unwanted space? If not, I will have to use another way (without the list) to achieve the intended result.

THanks in advance.

my code

```
<ol>
<li><div class="doSomething">testing1</div></li>
<li><div class="doSomething">testing2</div></li>
<li><div class="doSomething">testing3</div></li>
</ol>
```

the result looks like this

```
1. 
  testing1
2. 
  testing2
3. 
  testing3
```

Comment: divs can't be inside list items (invalid html).

Comment: Try using something like `normalise.css` first and see if it still looks different on each browser

Comment: @nevermind Why should that not be valid? `block` inside `list-item` is valid...

Comment: Why do you need the `div`s?

Comment: Floating the inner divs left should fix it but I don't know if that's a solution you'll want to persue

Comment: Could you setup fiddle, so we can see what is problem, exactly... (with all additional css applied to list)

Comment: @ nevermind hmm I'm very new in this.. I'll find out how to use jsfiddle with my questions

Comment: @Itay my divs have jquery functions that I added

Comment: @user3110299 So add them to the li's?

Answer (score 1):

I assume those list items are display: inline-block; here's how you can remove the space:

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>Item1</li><!--
    --><li>Item2</li><!--
    --><li>Item3</li>
</ul>
```

Adding these  will make the browser interpret the rest of the line as an html comment, removing the unwanted space

Comment: Achieving this with CSS would be smarter.

Comment: You would have to use negative margins that depend on the font size, I prefer adding html comments than using arbitrary negative margins. Inline blocks will interpret the empty space as a character. Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/T43TL/

Comment: You can achieve that with `word-spacing` and no special anything. http://jsfiddle.net/T43TL/1/

Comment: Well it does get messy on Chrome... On FF looks fine. weird

Comment: I think I also need to figure out how to post my comments and question here properly

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I'm not sure that having `<div>` within an `<li>` element is actually valid.</strike>
(I've just checked, and as per the comments on the OP, yes, `<div>`s are valid in `<li>` tags)

However, ignoring that, try removing the whitespace from between the elements...

```
<ol>
  <li><div class="doSomething">testing1</div></li
  ><li><div class="doSomething">testing2</div></li
  ><li><div class="doSomething">testing3</div></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It may help you.

```
ol {font-size:0}
ol li {font-size:12px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to do this through CSS only, it is possible. This problem is showing when you work with inline-block elements, as Jonas Grumann specified. It comes from the space that browsers add automatically between inline elements.

you can get rid of it setting the font-size to 0 on the parent element, and then resetting it to normal on the children elements:

```
ol {
    font-size: 0;
}

ol li {
    font-size: 14px;/*Or whatever size you need*/
}
```

However, and I'm unsure about it, this solution might have some problems for Android browser use.